# Image Stabilization optical flow

Tags: string, image, opencv, video-processing

I'm working on a image stabilization by using optical flow.
The algorithm that I've used is like this; first of all I have found good features to track in OpenCv "cvGoodFeaturesToTrack" and then I've estimated the optical flow by using this function for OpenCv as well "cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK". 
Now I want to stabilize the video sequence, which I think I need to take the average of the optical flow vectors. 
I'm working on a real time application so I can't use either SIFT or SURF. 
The problem that I don't know how take the average. 
Can anyone show me what to do?

Regards

Comment: Perhaps you could try with FAST features. There's an implementation in OpenCV 2.0.

Comment: The problem is not with choosing the features, The problem is how to make the average of the optical flow vectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to average anything. Optical flow will return the position of the "good features to track" in the second image. Transform the second image so that these features coincide with the features on the first image (use GetPerspectiveTransform).

I'll probably write an article on this soon on my website http://aishack.in/

Comment: Something in the lines of Ransac is probably needed to get this working robustly. Maybe that is included in the OpenCV functions considered.